# Remove Duplicates from combined text file

Tags: vb.net

How can I remove duplicates from my output text file? Can I add a distinct tag to my WriteAllLines statement? If so where would it fit?

```
Public Class newsenatefrm
    Private Sub generatebtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles generatebtn.Click
        Dim sen = IO.File.ReadLines("C:\temp\Senate113.txt").ToList()
        sen.AddRange(IO.File.ReadLines("C:\temp\RetiredSen.txt"))
        sen.AddRange(IO.File.ReadLines("C:\temp\NewSen.txt"))


        IO.File.WriteAllLines("Senate114.txt", sen.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Split(","c)(1)))

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: This doesn't look like VBA. Is it VB.Net? Please correct the tag

Comment: `sen.Distinct.OrderBy(...`

Answer (score 0):

Use a collection that doesn't support duplicates in the first place:

```
Public Class newsenatefrm
    Private Sub generatebtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles generatebtn.Click
        Dim sen = IO.File.ReadLines("C:\temp\Senate113.txt").ToHashSet()
        sen.UnionWith(IO.File.ReadLines("C:\temp\RetiredSen.txt"))
        sen.UnionWith(IO.File.ReadLines("C:\temp\NewSen.txt"))


        IO.File.WriteAllLines("Senate114.txt", sen.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Split(","c)(1)))

    End Sub
End Class
```